# simple query not works if inside a mysql function

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm using a query inside a function to get value in database, but it is returning NULL.
the same query outside the function works fine.

**my function**

```
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT `value` FROM data WHERE `k` = 29 AND `entity` = "abr9f9" LIMIT 1);
END
```

**the test using function and the same raw query**

```
SELECT 
    GETSTATIC() AS static,
    (SELECT `value` FROM data WHERE `k` = 29 AND `entity` = "abr9f9" LIMIT 1) AS raw
```

**is returning**

```
static     raw
------     ---
NULL       175
```

I think this is because i'm not choosing the return field VALUE in the function.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example of code, between BEGIN and END, isn't going to return your expected result, because this notation is used to define a procedure, while the second example is plain SQL DML.

If you want, you can read about [CREATE PROCEDURE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) syntax, specifically about OUT parameter.

**EDIT:**

Try this:

```
create function GETSTATIC()
returns integer 
return (SELECT `value` FROM data WHERE `k` = 29 AND `entity` = "abr9f9" LIMIT 1);
```

then you would call it like:

```
select GETSTATIC() as static;
```

Comment: I need this as a function because I have to run inside other queries. There is now way to return value as expected using function?

Comment: There is, please read my linked article, there's example about creating a function which e.g. RETURNS CHAR(50)

Comment: A compatible but more complete definition should include `DETERMINISTIC` `READS SQL DATA` right after `RETURNS INT`.

Comment: If OP reads the article I linked to, they will know this too.